# How to write Junit Test cases for Executor service having multiple callable statement

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

So in my service layer I have a public method calling a private method (Method to be covered in JUnit), which in turn calls other private method for some computations.
I need to write JUnit for this method.

Mocking the callable is not helping

```
private void Method1(Long num, Map<String,Object> result){
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedhreadPool(3);
    List<Callable<SomeVo> callables = Array.asList(
        getCallable(this::method1,num),
        getCallable(this::method2,num),
        getCallable(this.method3,num));

    try{
        List<Future<SomeVo> futures = es.involeAll();
        executor.shutdown();

        for(Future<Somevo> f : futures){
            somemethod(f,result);
        }
    } catch (InteruptedException e) { }

private SomeVo method1(Long num){
    return someVo; 
}

private void somemethod(Future<SomeVo> f ,Map<String,Object> res){
    result.put("key", f.get());
}
```

Comment: Please: even when just putting up examples here, follow java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase(), always, and they should include a verb.

Answer (score 2):

Simply refactor your code a little bit, extracting the `Method1` to some kind of interface/abstract class and providing a list of the `callables` as a method parameter (just use *Dependency Injection* pattern). Then in your public method you can use some private implementation for the interface.

This way you can provide a set of your mocks/test implementation and see whether they were called or not

What I mean in a scratch (treat this code as pseudo code example, you should focus on refactoring here to make it properly) is

```
public abstract class ResultProcessor {
    public void processResults(Long num, Map<String,Object> result, List<Callable<SomeVo> callables){
        // ...
    }
}

// then in the class of your public method create private implementation

...

public void yourPublicMethod() {
    // instead of calling Method1(num, result)
    new Method1Processor().processResults(num, result);
}

private static class Method1Processor extends ResultProcessor {
    public void processResults(Long num, Map<String,Object> result, List<Callable<SomeVo> callables){
        List<Callable<SomeVo> callables = Array.asList(
                 getCallable(this::method1,num),
                 getCallable(this::method2,num),
                 getCallable(this.method3,num));

        super.processResults(num, result, callables);
    }

    private SomeVo method1(Long num){
        return someVo; // yes you still have access to fields of parent class :)
    }
    private void somemethod(Future<SomeVo> f ,Map<String,Object> res){
        result.put("key", f.get()); // here is the same
    }
}
```

Now you can easily provide your own implementation to test `ResultProcessor` logic

Comment: I want to mock this part: List<Callable<SomeVo> callables = Array.asList(
                 getCallable(this::method1,num),
                 getCallable(this::method2,num),
                 getCallable(this.method3,num));